# Correct way to jump back and forth between two branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch

If I create a branch:

```
hg branch branch-A
```

and commit to it:

```
hg commit -m "improvement A-1"
```

and then create a second branch:

```
hg branch branch-B
```

and commit to it:

```
hg commit -m "improvement B-1"
```

**If I want to add my next change to branch-A do I simply type:**

```
hg branch branch-A
```

**and commit to it as before:**

```
hg commit -m "improvement A-2"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
hg branch
```

always creates a branch (although it warns you if the branch already exists.)  To switch to an existing branch, either

```
hg update -r <some revision in that branch>
```

or

```
hg update <that branch>
```

will switch to that branch.

Comment: Also, I usually create a tag for revisions for which I'm starting a new branch. This helps me when I need to update to that specific revision (it happens quite often).